# Weird findings initializing the array with numpy.NAN

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'am having some trouble when  initializing a numpy array with numpy.NAN as below.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros(2)
>>> a
array([ 0.,  0.])
>>> a[:] = numpy.NAN
>>> a
array([ nan,  nan])
>>> a[0] is numpy.NAN
False
```

Why is that? I have tried to initilize a single variable with NAN and get var is numpy.NAN as True. What happends when NAN is assign to an array?

And another question is when some of the elements in the arrary is NAN, how can I distinguish them from others? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try with `numpy.isnan`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a NaN. It's just that `is` doesn't work the way you think it does with NumPy arrays. When you assign

```
a[:] = numpy.NAN
```

NumPy doesn't actually fill `a` with references to the `numpy.NAN` object. Instead, it fills the array with doubles with NaN values at C level.

When you then access an array element with `a[0]`, NumPy has no record of the original object used to initialize that cell. It just has the numeric value. It has to construct a new Python object to wrap that value, and the new wrapper is not the same object as `numpy.NAN`. Thus, the `is` check returns `False`.

Note that generally, comparing numbers with `is` is a bad idea anyway. Usually, what you want is `==`, to compare their numeric values. However, `==` also returns `False` for NaNs, so what you need is `numpy.isnan`:

```
>>> numpy.isnan(a[0])
True
>>> numpy.isnan(a)
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```